# Double PHP URL query GET

Tags: php, get

Basically my question is:

mysite.php?searchword=vinegar?page=2

In the above url is it possible to GET both the search value (which here is vinegar) and the page value (here 2) with PHP code?

It comes from searching a large mysql table for the word vinegar, and then paginating the results.
If this is not how possible, please could you suggest a way to do this

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you having? Your query string parameters should easily be accessible via $_GET['searchword'] and $_GET['page'].

Comment: @j08691 yes if you use `&` instead of multiple `?`

Comment: @Lan Try use search before posting questions like that, these answer are easy to find

-j08691 not via this syntax.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti - Ah good catch, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
mysite.php?searchword=vinegar&page=2
```

and in php

```
$search = $_GET['searchword'];
$page = $_GET['page'];
```

Comment: Or get it with $_REQUEST['page']` if You post the values

Comment: @silly Actually you should use `$_POST['page']` if you post the values, but this is completely irrelevant as we're specifically talking about how to build the query string.

Answer (score 3):

The question mark in a URL denotes the beginning of the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure). Your URL may contain only one query string. Within the query string, multiple key=value pairs are separated by an ampersand, &:

```
mysite.php?searchword=vinegar&page=2
```

PHP makes the contents of your query string available via the [super-global](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) associative array [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

```
$_GET['searchword']; # "vinegar"
$_GET['page']; # "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

No because the syntax is wrong. URL parameters should be in the format:

```
mysite.php?searchword=vinegar&page=2
```

And then you use `$_GET['chword']` and `$_GET['page']` to retrieve them in PHP

Answer (score 1):

yes, use &

```
mysite.php?searchword=vinegar&page=2
```

Answer (score 1):

There should only be 1 question mark after the `.php`.
The URL should be written like this: `mysite.php?searchword=vinegar&page=2`, then PHP will get both the searchword and page value.

Answer (score 1):

mysite.php?searchword=vinegar&page=2

```
$word = $_GET["searchword"]
$page = $_GET["page"]
```

Thats all you need.